# Applications crashing

Tags: crashes

I have some applications crashing.

The message says

The application XXX (process YYY) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

One of applications who is crashing is Google Maps. It is crashing all the time even if I don't run it. Only uninstallation helps.

What does this crashing mean?

Comment: Certainly it means problems. There's no generic answer to this problem -- except to contact the developer...

Comment: Developers vary. I think it should be either hardware or software problem with entire device.

Comment: Then this is a case where "custumer support" would suggest a factory reset, which should clean things up if it's a software problem -- or say it's rather hardware related if the problem persists.

Comment: I happened to have this issue when the file partitions on the phone are almost full. Try to clear up some space from the data partition with least apps you use by uninstalling them. I guess 50mb of removed apps  would be fine to try. And check if crashes continue, like google maps.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/16575)